# ebook-convert not converting epub to pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, epub, calibre

```
1% 
Converting input to HTML... 
InputFormatPlugin: EPUB Input running on /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.epub 
Found HTML cover content/calibre_title_page.html 
Parsing all content... 
34% 
Running transforms on ebook... 
Merging user specified metadata... 
Detecting structure... 
Flattening CSS and remapping font sizes... 
Source base font size is 12.00000pt 
Removing fake margins... 
Cleaning up manifest... 
Trimming unused files from manifest... 
Creating PDF Output... 
67% 
Creating PDF Output
```

Below is the code that I am using in a PHP file

```
$output = shell_exec("ebook-convert test.epub mej.pdf");
echo $output;
```

Please help me out its required for completion of a project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also it run without any error but it doesn't convert it to PDF

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you tried using the output file as an absolute path (i.e., /home/kuldeep/mej.pdf or something similar)? Also, is there more to the debug print? It appears that there is some missing (after 67%)

Comment: I've removed thank you notes... but it still does not look like answerable question - most likely your input data is not good enough, but you need to investigate it yourself/report as bug...

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis this is the exact output that is am getting on the screen .. however I get this on Shell .. 

   The cover image has an id != "cover". Renaming to work around bug in Nook Color

Comment: but apart of that "The cover image has an id != "cover". Renaming to work around bug in Nook Color" it converts perfectly fine through shell

Comment: It may have to do with file permissions (http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=82334)